# If $f_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number then $\lim_{n\to \infty} (f_{n-2}+{1-\sqrt 5\over 2}f_{n-1})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, fibonacci-numbers

If $f_n$ is the $n$th *Fibonacci number* then what is  the value of $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(f_{n-2}+{1-\sqrt 5\over 2}f_{n-1}\right)?$$
With direct calculation I saw the first four terms are approximately $(-0.62,0.39,-0.24,0.15)$. It seems that the limit approaches $0$. But how to show it analytically?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet%27s_formula

Answer (score 1):

Using [Binet's Formula](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Binet%27s_Formula),

for $a+b=1, ab=-1$ with  $a>b$

we need $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{a^{n-2}-b^{n-2}}{a-b}+b\cdot\dfrac{a^{n-1}-b^{n-1}}{a-b}\right)$$

$$=\dfrac1{a-b}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(a^{n-2}-b^{n-2}+b(a^{n-1}-b^{n-1})\right)$$

$$=\dfrac1{a-b}\lim_{n\to\infty} (a^{n-2}(1+ab)+2b^{n-1})$$

Now  $1+ab=0$

and as $|b|<1,\lim_{n\to\infty}b^{n-1}=0$

Comment: Oh yes since ${1-\sqrt 5\over 2}\approx -0.618$ using Binet's formula the limit is 0.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\psi^{n}=f_{n}\psi +f_{n-1}$, where $\psi={1-\sqrt 5\over 2}$. This is easily proved by induction since $\psi^2=\psi+1$. Therefore,
$$
f_{n-2}+{1-\sqrt 5\over 2}f_{n-1} = f_{n-2}+\psi f_{n-1} = \psi^{n-1} \to 0
$$
because $|\psi|<1$.